# Sort value from nested object using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to sort an object by SpaceType, TimeInterval and Price. It's a nested object as shown below. Can someone suggest me a sample on how to sort it in an efficient way using c# 4.0

ParkingFacility -> Cost -> TimeInterval

```
"VendorID": 1200,
"FacilityID": 931,
"ParkingType": "Garage",
"Price": null,
"BARTValidationRequired": null,
"LotName": "Civic Center Garage",
"City": "San Francisco",
"Street": "355 McAllister Street",
"Neighborhood": "Hayes Valley/Civic Center",
"Latitude": "37.780200",
"Longitude": "-122.417800",
"Distance": "",
"Availability": "Space Available: <b>62%</b> (515/843) <br/>Current Price: <b>N/A</b><br />6:00 AM-12:00 AM",
"Details": null,
"Hours": "Sunday : 9:00 AM-10:00 PM <br />Monday : 6:00 AM-12:00 AM <br />Tuesday : 6:00 AM-12:00 AM <br />Wednesday : 6:00 AM-12:00 AM <br />Thursday : 6:00 AM-12:00 AM <br />Friday : 6:00 AM-12:00 AM <br />Saturday : 8:00 AM-12:00 AM <br />",
"Entrance": null,
"Contact": "",
"TodayTimings": "6:00 AM-12:00 AM",
"TotalParkingSpace": 843,
"AvailableParkingSpace": 515,
"OccupiedParkingSpace": 328,
"PercentFull": 38,
"Rendering": 3,
"ZoneID": 0,
"OwnershipAgencyType": null,
"Cost": [
[
    {
        "DayType": "Thursday",
        "SpaceType": "Motorcycle",
        "Description": "Motorcycle: Flatrate",
        "TimeInterval": 0,
        "Cost": "$5.00",
        "FaciltyID": 0
    },
    {
        "DayType": "Thursday",
        "SpaceType": "Auto",
        "Description": null,
        "TimeInterval": 0,
        "Cost": "$5.00",
        "FaciltyID": 0
    }
],
[
    {
        "DayType": "MondayToFridayExceptHolidays",
        "SpaceType": "Auto",
        "Description": "Early Bird: Flat rate. Mon-Fri (excl. Tue): In by 9AM/Out by 7PM;No Tues Early Bird",
        "TimeInterval": 0,
        "Cost": "$15.00",
        "FaciltyID": 0
    }
],
[
    {
        "DayType": "Thursday",
        "SpaceType": "Auto",
        "Description": "Per hour",
        "TimeInterval": 60,
        "Cost": "$3.00",
        "FaciltyID": 0
    },
    {
        "DayType": "Thursday",
        "SpaceType": "Auto",
        "Description": "12-Hour Max",
        "TimeInterval": 720,
        "Cost": "$24.00",
        "FaciltyID": 0
    },
    {
        "DayType": "Thursday",
        "SpaceType": "Auto",
        "Description": "24-Hour Max/Lost Tkt",
        "TimeInterval": 0,
        "Cost": "$30.00",
        "FaciltyID": 0
    },
    {
        "DayType": "Thursday",
        "SpaceType": "Auto",
        "Description": null,
        "TimeInterval": 0,
        "Cost": "$30.00",
        "FaciltyID": 0
     }
 ]]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you have it in a structure in c# you can use linq to order by multiple items.

e.g.

```
 listOfPeople.OrderBy(person => person.LastName)
        .ThenBy(person => person.FirstName)
         .ThenBy(person => person.DOB)
```

This is a trivial example of course but depending on how you wanted them sorted - if inside their own container or all as one - you could run this iterator. It is quite efficient - better programmers than you and I made it so.

Probably tougher is how to sort the spaceType - as just doing it like that would do it alphabetically which might not be what you want.

Comment: The problem i am having is not the sort order but how to sort the root structure which is parking facility object based on an nested object called Time interval. ParkingFacility contains a cost object . Cost object contains a FaciltyPrice object which is a list of price object. From the list<price> object i can get the travel time but sorting the parking facility by travel time is where i am having no clue how to do it. Refer my object posted. Its is the exact json representation of my current object which i need to sort

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a cut down model in code with just the elements that you are wanting to sort with - and also a desc of how you want it to look. I am still not 100% on which object you want to sort and what conditions you are wanting to sort them by. More than willing to help tho!

Comment: rangitatanz: thanks for the help. I figured it out. The logic i used initially was not right.